# Naming convention for Private Properties

Tags: swift, swift3, naming-conventions

I've seen underscore used as a prefix for private properties

```
private var _aPrivateVar: String = "I am private"
```

I've seen them not used

```
private var aPrivateVar: String = "I am private"
```

Syntactically, it makes no difference and my *preference* is to not use them.  However, what's the accepted convention *in Swift* so that I pick the right habit up?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In this [Swift Guide style](https://github.com/raywenderlich/swift-style-guide), you can find a similar reference:

```
private var centerString: String {
  return "(\(x),\(y))"
}
```

In [*The swift Programming Language book (swift 4 beta)*](https://itunes.apple.com/us/book/the-swift-programming-language/id1002622538?mt=11) (link to ), you can also find these examples:

page 812:

```
private var privateInstance = somePrivateClass()
```

page 822:

```
private var privateVariable = 12
```

Excerpt From: Apple Inc. “The Swift Programming Language (Swift 4 beta).” iBooks.

I do believe that the second option is the correct way to go.

Comment: Great - I think that's pretty definitive!