# Name convention for private variables and public computed properties in swift

Tags: swift

In my code I have been using an underscore prefix `_` before private variables and then using the same name for computed properties without the underscore.

```
private var _all: double
public var all: double {
    get {
        return self._all
    }
    set {
        this._all = newValue
    }
}
```

In most places I have seen this approach being used.
But since convention is to use camelCase, what is the right way to name the private variable?

Comment: Just `public var all: Double` – in Swift there is no need to separate between “instance variable“ and “accessor method” unless you have specific needs (such as side effects of the accessors).

Comment: See here:
[naming-convention-for-private-properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45521678/naming-convention-for-private-properties)

Answer (score 0):

Each variable should use the camelCase. But this is just a convention. [Swift Docs](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/TheBasics.html)

Personally I don't like the character _. I used to see it when coding in C#

Answer (score 0):

I know you asked this a long time ago, but since I was searching for the answer to the same question and didn't really find it here, I felt that I would post what I feel is a definitive answer (from the Swift documentation). If you scroll down to the last example in [this](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/documentation/the-swift-programming-language/properties/#Property-Wrappers) section of the Swift Properties documentation, you will find that prefacing the backing variable name with an underscore is the recommended thing to do.